# How can I refer my Neo4j embedded Db to getGraphDb() method?

Tags: java, swing, neo4j

I want to develop a piece of software that helps the user to open and close a Neo4j embedded server within my java application. Practically, I click the button and the web admin tool should be opened in the default web browser. However, I am stuck because I have a problem with the line code

```
InternalAbstractGraphDatabase graphdb = getGraphDb();
```

I don't understand how to open my implemented db which is in the variable:

```
 private static GraphDatabaseService BORO_DB;
```

and has path:

```
public static String DB_PATH;
```

Below the code:

```
final Variable var = new Variable(true);

InternalAbstractGraphDatabase graphdb = getGraphDb();
final WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv;
srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper( graphdb );

final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Show Graph - Start Server");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        if (var.getVar()){
            var.setVar(false);
            btnNewButton.setText("Graph - Stop Server");
            srv.start();

               try {

                 String url = "http://localhost:7474";
                 java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
               }
               catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
               }

        }else{
            var.setVar(true);
            btnNewButton.setText("Show Graph - Start Server");
            srv.stop();
        }   
    }
});
```

May you teach me how to link my DB (BORO_DB) to getGraphDb()?

Thank you

Comment: Is this Quentin Tarantino? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DB_PATH, you can instantiate BORO_DB like this:

```
BORO_DB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

srv=new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper((GraphDatabaseAPI) BORO_DB);
```

Comment: Do you mean `BORO_DB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );`
`final WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv= new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper((GraphDatabaseAPI)BORO_DB);` I have tried it but I have a new problem: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:881)
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:909)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.applyChanges(Config.java:123)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.<init>(Config.java:89)

Comment: Oops sorry, edited it. You need to have concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ for the other error

Comment: My problem doesn't seem related to a missing jar, rather there is a java.lang.NullPointerException that refers to the first line code mentioned above `BORO_DB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );`

Comment: What is the content of DB_PATH? And please post the NullPOinterException too

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, my problem was stupid. I had just repeated twice the first line. It is amazing, three days on this problem thank youuuuuuuu